# Why is my iOs launcher and appicon not applying?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need some help figuring out why I can't get a launch icon and appicon to apply to my project. I am running xcode Version 6.3.2. Note: another developer has already applied an appicon The following I have tried:

I created an asset catalog and added new app icon and launcher image via the plus sign button in the lower left of the asset window.

In the general settings of the app I clicked on "Use Asset Catalog" for both the launcher icon source and app icon source. I selected my asset catalog and it prompts me to migrate images, which I did.

My icon and launch icon are not applying even though I have followed these steps. How do I figure out why they are not applying?

EDIT:
All of the slots for the different devices are filled with a .png image. Now that I look at it I wonder if this could be the issue- when I select use asset catalog it migrates my images which creates a new subset of launch icons and all of those slots are empty. With that subset selected my project builds fine. If I select my original subset with the icons in the slots the build fails with message - The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content. Same for the launch icons.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the app from the simulator or device and try again. Due to caching optimizations, sometimes resources are not updated if the name doesn't change.

You might also need to clean your project and rebuild it. Select Clean from the Product menu in Xcode.

Comment: I'm new to this, how do I delete the app from the simulator?

Comment: The same way you would remove an app from a regular iPhone / iPad. Hold long on the icon, press the little X.

Comment: You can also completely reset the simulator using the Reset Content and Settings menu command.

Comment: I've tried to reset the simulator, but its still the same appicon. :( Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot, but your Asset Catalog may not be included in your target. Select the catalog file, open the File Inspector and check the Target Membership.  Although I believe @Dave Batton has provided the correct answer.

Comment: The asset was included in my target. :( Anything else you think I could try?

Comment: Are the asset library image files appropriate for the simulator (OS and device combination) that you are using? For example if you only have the normal and 2x versions of the icon, and you run on the iPhone 6 Plus simulator, you'll get the default iOS icon.

Comment: All of the slots for the different devices are filled with a .png image. Now that I look at it I wonder if this could be the issue- when I select use asset catalog it migrates my images which creates a new subset of launch icons and all of those slots are empty. With that subset selected my project builds fine. If I select my original subset with the icons in the slots the build fails with message - The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content.